# CSS: Covering entire block of element

Tags: html, css

Having a problem trying to fill the entire block with `background-color` when hovering over an item. When hovering over it only covers the text, not the entire block.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home"> Example </a></li>
        <li><a href="#home"> Stuff </a></li>
        <li><a href="#home"> Things </a></li>
        <li><a href="#home"> Content </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And my style:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  padding: 8px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: did you try `display:block` to both `li` and `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You have added `overflow` property to your `ul` and it was not allowing `a` to show its full width. Just removed it and I guess it works fine.

```css
    nav {
      width: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: end;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }

    li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    a {
      padding: 8px 14px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }

    a:hover {
      background-color: #333;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#home"> Example </a></li>
              <li><a href="#home"> Stuff </a></li>
              <li><a href="#home"> Things </a></li>
              <li><a href="#home"> Content </a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `margin: 0; padding: 0;` from `UL` and remove `overflow: hidden;`

Refer below:

```css
 nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  padding: 8px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home"> Example </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Stuff </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Things </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Content </a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    nav {
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: end;
       }

     ul {
         list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

    li {
          display: inline-block;
       }

      a {
         padding: 8px 14px;
         text-decoration: none;
          color: white;
       }

       a:hover {
               color: #333;
          border-radius: 6px;
       }
```

try this css. Do not use background color property only use color

Answer (score 0):

you can make the following changes

[image: smaple image]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
          <li><a href="#home"> Example </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Stuff </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Things </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Content </a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. you have to set a padding on your a:hover to cover the entire navigation set the ul padding and margin to 0 as well so you can attain and cover the entire li

```css
 nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  padding: 8px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 11px 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home"> Example </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Stuff </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Things </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Content </a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code

Comment: @Sfili_81 added some thanks for the reminder. sleepy head here :P

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:block` to the `a` element.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  padding: 8px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home"> Example </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Stuff </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Things </a></li>
          <li><a href="#home"> Content </a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to move your nav css style to your ul style.
the nav tag do not need styling (in you case). What needs styling is : ul, li, a.
Keep in mind that html tags have a default styling applied by your navigator. that css should be reset before starting to style any tag. In your example we would add to the ul tag:

```
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;

}
```

Then you apply style accordingly to what you desire. For example :

```
nav {
 /* Nothing here */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;

 /* This is important */
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;

  width: 100%; /* width 100% has no effect here. It can be safely removed */
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

[example output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw9VW.png)